# HTML data-binding automatically strips my input string

Tags: python, html, flask

HTML with data-binding

```
 Location:<br>
  <select name="location">
   {% for item in data %}
     <option value={{ item[0] }}>{{ item[0] }}</option>
   {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

[image]

I have a form that looks like this. 
The location selection is retrieved from the actual database like:

```
@app.route('/events', methods = ['post', 'get'])
def events():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM location')
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    data = [row for row in rows]
    cursor.close()
    return render_template('events.html', data = data)
```

Using `{{ item[0] }}` seems like it's retrieving the name of the `Location` correctly, but when I actually send it as a value, it just strips it and submits `1st` instead of `1st Street` as the image below shows:

[image]

I just printed it on this page for testing purpose.

How come it shows correctly when I just put it on HTML, but it strips the actual data submitted?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Put quotes around the value within the option tag: `<option value="{{ item[0] }}">{{ item[0] }}</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotation marks around your value:

```
<option value="{{ item[0] }}">{{ item[0] }}</option>
```

But in general it's better practice to give your location an ID, and just put the location ID as value and the streetname as thing you actually see in the select box.